# Is it possible to finish a thread externally in java debugging?

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, netbeans, netbeans-7

I would like to know if it's possible to finish a thread externally in debug, (I don't mind if it's in an unsafe way, by deprecated Thread.stop()).

I am using Netbeans 7.1.2, and options for thread debugging are make current, suspend, interrupt, but there is no stop option.

Comment: @assylias interrupt would only work if thread is in sleep, wait, join, or interruptible channel, but not otherwise. I think the only alternative is to do it programatically..I don't know if it's an IDE limitation or a JDK (lack of) feature

Comment: You can catch Interrupt pretty much anytime. If you are looping in your run function say using a `while` loop, you can check the interrupt flag as the loop condition or somewhere in your loop. If you are calling blocking functions like queue.put(...), they all throw InterruptedException on Interrupt.

Comment: @goblinjuice I wanted to do debug it without changing the code, but I understand your point

Answer (score -1):

You can try this insted of thread.stop() method.

```
class TestThread implements Runnable{

 private Thread thread;

 public TestThread()
 {
   thread=new Thread(this);
 }

 public void stopThread()
 {
   thread=null;
 } 
 public void run()
 {
   while(thread!=null)
   {
     //Some Code here
   }
 }
}

class Main
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
     TestThread tt=new TestThread();
     //sleep for some time
     tt.stopThread();
   }
}
```

when ever you want to stop the thread call stopThread() function as in the above example.